# Consequences of positive matches in Bloom filters

Tags: performance, data-structures, bloom-filter

Assumptions:

- The usernames of registered users are stored in a set
- I want to use a Bloom filter to make lookups faster.
- The Bloom filter as a certain probability of false-positives (0.1%)

When a new user wants to register, in most cases, my UI tells them "this name is not in use, you're good to go".

**But what does the backend need to do if a positive match is found?**

The result might be a false-positive. Would finding out the true answer not add to time-complexity and thus make Bloom filters inefficient in many cases?

Telling a user "Name aready in use, choose a different oe" might not be so bad, but what about other use cases where you cannot be wrong.

Answer (score 2):

The general model for using Bloom filters goes like this:

1. Query the filter to see whether the answer *might* be yes.
2. If the Bloom filter says no, the answer is definitely no.
3. If the Bloom filter says yes, the answer *might* be yes, so query a more accurate data structure to get a final determination.

Bloom filters really shine when step (3) is of the form “query some server somewhere to search a gigantic database to see if you have the item in question.” In that case, reducing the number of times the server needs to get pinged in order to make a determination can lead to huge performance gains on the client and reduce the load on the servers.

On the other hand, if you’re storing a small data set locally on a machine, then a Bloom filter isn’t likely to do all that much because querying that data set directly is probably going to be fast enough for all your needs.

Answer (score 2):

Bloomfilter is used in cases only when you want to detect whether an incoming word already exists in our database.

To be specific bloomfilter outputs either

- Yes- that means a word may or may not exist in our database
- No- that means it is 100 percent sure that the word doesn't exist

Moreover, a false positive should not harm in your case but still, if you are really worried, the errorrate of bloomfilters is given by the formula:

errorrate = [1-(1-(1/m))^(k*i)]^k

where i is number of current insertions, i. e. if you are inserting 20th word in the bloom filter then i=20
      k is number of hash functions
      m is size of bit array

So you can go ahead and minimize it to suite your need.

Moreover the optimal number of hash functions used is given by

k=(m/n)log 2

where n is total number of words to be inserted. So you can choose the number of hash functions accordingly.